# Magento2, Admin panel Weight Field not showing in product edit or add

Tags: php, magento, admin, product, magento2

The weight field does not show up when i edit or add a product, On saving this changes my already added products to Virtual. I have checked everything in the attribute sets, etc, and it shows up just fine. but still does not get displayed anywhere on the admin page for editing the product

Comment: check console and error logs

Comment: you have virtual product?

Comment: No, i don not have a virtual product.. but as weight is not displayed. it changes from simple/configurable to virtual